# Variable in Handlebars path

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to reference a variable in my Handlebars template to use in my `#each` block. However, I can't seem to get it working:

```
// doesn't work, logs nothing
{{#each collections.[this.sectionIndex] }}
    {{ log this.title }}
{{/each}}
```

The variable is available in the page, as confirmed by logging:

```
{{ log this.sectionIndex }} // --> writing
```

The only difference I'm seeing so far is that `this.sectionIndex` is a string above, while the value below is part of Handlebars' syntax and (I assume) processed differently:

```
// does work
{{#each collections.[writing] }}
    {{ log this.title }}
{{/each}}
```

For reference, this is what `collections` looks like:

```
{ 
  pages: [ 
    { title: 'About Us',
      url: 'about',
      ...
    },
    ... 
  ],
  writing: [ 
    { title: 'page 2',
      contents: '...',
      ...
    },
    { title: 'page 1',
      contents: '<p>Writing goes here.</p>\n',
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use a helper for this?

Comment: What is `this` bound to?. Also, do you see the log in any for at all when you look the DOM?

Comment: `this` is bound to the context of the template, which in this case contains information about the page it's processing and other metadata about the site (I am using Handlebars as a part of the Metalsmith static site generator). i.e., `this = {partials: {...}, title: 'Writing', template: 'section.hbt', sectionIndex: 'writing', ...}`

Comment: the unniversal way is to just feed the data you need to the template; it's easier to "steer" in programming languages than logic-less templates.